# Badge on TabBar when built by Interface Builder

Tags: ios, tabbar, badge

Is it possible to programmable set a badge value on a TabBar which is made in Interface Builder (Xcode4).  I have four tabs and I would like to have a badge on the forth tab if there is unread items in the inbox that is behind the tab.

Or do I have to rebuild the tabbar by code to be able to do this?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it as -

```
UITabBarItem *tbi = (UITabBarItem*)[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3];

[tbi setBadgeValue:@"1"];
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where do I set it? In the delegate?

Comment: you can do it in app delegate or anywhere in your project.

Comment: Will try it in the Delegate.  I assume it is not possible to set a badge on a button, is it?

Comment: button ?? isn't these are tabs of your tab bar controller?

Comment: When I click on the tab which will hopefully have the badge, there is a screen with some buttons. One of them is for the inbox.

Comment: the above code will show bedge on forth tab of your tab bar controller not on a button.

Comment: Sorry to report it didn't work. I put the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Is there somewhere better?

Comment: I put it in viewDidLoad on the first screen and it worked. Thanks a lot!